# Pass input date values to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I am unable to pass date values to constructor :Attempt to deference null object:
Vf page:

```
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
     <apex:outputLabel value="From Date" />
     <apex:actionRegion > 
        **<apex:inputField value="{!opp.From_Date__c}">** 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                reRender="ajax" />
          </apex:inputField> 
     </apex:actionRegion>
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Controller:

```
 public Opportunity opp{get;set;}//property
 public controller_VfProdPage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
 {
    opp = new Opportunity(); 
    startMonth =  opp.From_Date__c.month();
    numMonth= new list<integer>();
    Integer monthBtwn = opp.From_Date__c.monthsBetween(opp.To_Date__c);    
}
```

Comment: From_Date__c is coming null

Comment: when your actionSupport executes, the values in the actionRegion are sent to the controller.  Your constructor doesn't get called again. What is in the rerendered id=`ajax`? Do you reference {!opp.from_date__c}` within id=`ajax` ?

Comment: @SalesforceLearner I think there are some basic coding rules that you may not understand. A constructor is evaluated when the page is loaded, and is not ever evaluated again. If you want to do something with the field value, you will need to have separate methods. Please look at the solution provided below by Tushar Sharma and see what the extra method allows.

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem > <apex:outputLabel value="From Date" />
     <apex:actionRegion > **<apex:inputField value="{!opp.From_Date__c}">** 
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!priValue}" 
                            rerender="none"
      reRender="ajax" /></apex:inputField> </apex:actionRegion>
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Controller:

```
    public controller_VfProdPage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
         {
         opp = new Opportunity(); 
        startMonth =  opp.From_Date__c.month()!=null?opp.From_Date__c.month():Date.today();  //add default value
  numMonth= new list<integer>();
  Integer monthBtwn = opp.From_Date__c!=null && opp.To_Date__c!=null?opp.From_Date__c.monthsBetween(opp.To_Date__c): 0;

        }

    public void priValue() {
         system.debug('----------------->'+opp.From_Date__c);
       startMonth =  opp.From_Date__c.month();
       numMonth= new list<integer>();
       Integer monthBtwn = opp.From_Date__c.monthsBetween(opp.To_Date__c);
    }
```

in your constructor `opp.From_Date__c` is null and you are trying to use it. First give it any value. Same with the  `opp.From_Date__c.monthsBetween(opp.To_Date__c);` validate that these are not null.

Comment: I know how to pass value dynamically to controller..I have created two input field in vf page.

Comment: you don't need to do anything extra. But before using these field in constructor validate that they are not null. Otherwise perform some action using button and in your button debug these field and you will get your value there.

Comment: Not able to resolve

Comment: @SalesforceLearner Please check my update answer.

Comment: I need to get values ..you are telling me check condition whether it is null or not....it's coming null after giving input on vf page ..how to pass values to controller that is my question

Comment: are you sure you are getting null value after page select. Also why are you using `apex:actionRegion` in your code.

Comment: Yes sure tried ..showing null values

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling opp.From_Date__c.month(); you are calling .month() on null so you need to first check for null value in following way

```
public controller_VfProdPage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
 {
 opp = new Opportunity(); 
 startMonth =  opp.From_Date__c.month()!=null?opp.From_Date__c.month():null;
  numMonth= new list<integer>();
  Integer monthBtwn = opp.From_Date__c!=null && opp.To_Date__c!=null?opp.From_Date__c.monthsBetween(opp.To_Date__c): 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I need to get the user input from vf page ...I have two fields date From and To which on vf page .And it's value is coming null after giving values to it!

Comment: constructor is called only when page load first time so you can't get updated value inside constructor. the only way is call a controller side function described by Tushar

Comment: Still it is showing null values